# Combining Hadoop MapReduce and database queries

Tags: database, data-binding, hadoop, mapreduce

A certain job I'm running needs to collect some metadata from a DB (MySQL, although that's not as relevant) before processing some large HDFS files. This metadata will be added to data in the files and passed on to the later map/combine/reduce stages.

I was wondering where the "correct" place to put this query might be. I need the metadata to be available when the mapper begins, but placing it there seems redundant, as every Mapper will execute the same query. How can I (if at all) perform this query once and share its results across all the mappers? Is there a common way to share data between all the nodes performing a task (other than writing it to HDFS)? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have your MYSql query  in your main function and the result of the query can be stored in a string. Then you can set the variable to the Hadoop Job Configuration object. The variables set in Configuration object can be accessed by all mappers. 

Your main class looks like this....
`JobConf conf = new JobConf(Driver.class);`
`String metainfo = <You metadata Info goes here>;`

`conf.set("metadata",metainfo);`

So in you Map Class you can access the metadata value as follows

`publi class Map(...){`
`String sMetaInfo="";`     
`public void configure(JobConf job) {`
`sMetaInfo= job.get("metadata"); // Getting the metadata value from Job Configureation Object`
`}`

`public void map(....){`

`// Map Function`

`}`
`}`

Comment: Additionally, if your metadata is too large to be stored in the Configuration, then you should look into using the DistributedCache. Acquire the metadata from the DB in your driver, save to file and then add the file to the DistributedCache - the file will then be available in each mapper for you to load into memory and append as needed

Answer (score 0):

I would use swoop if you have the cloudera distribution for ease.  I usually program with cascading in java and for db sources use dbmigrate as a source "tap" making dbs a first class citizen.  When using pks with dbmigrate, the performance has been adequate.